# Difference between return value and local variable

Tags: c++, constructor, return-value, local-variables, conversion-operator

Suppose I have

```
#include <string>

class A
{
public:
    template<class T>
    operator T();

    A child();
};

void f()
{
    A a;
    std::string s1 = a;            // ok
    std::string s2 = a.child();    // error (line 34)

    s1 = a;           // error (line 36)
    s2 = a.child();   // error (line 37)

}
```

The std::string constructor can take either a char* or an std::string reference, which is why the assignment is ambiguous. But why does my compiler (VC++10) complain about the second assignment but not the first?

I am looking for a way to give precedence to the template conversion operator rather than the overloaded constructor.

I get the following errors:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Plasma4Test, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Plasma4Test.cpp
1>d:\bitbucket\vx\projects\plasma4test\plasma4test.cpp(34): error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'A' to 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
1>d:\bitbucket\vx\projects\plasma4test\plasma4test.cpp(36): error C2593: 'operator =' is ambiguous
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xstring(772): could be 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>::operator =(_Elem)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xstring(767): or       'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>::operator =(const _Elem *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xstring(762): or       'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>::operator =(const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(std::string, A)'
1>d:\bitbucket\vx\projects\plasma4test\plasma4test.cpp(37): error C2593: 'operator =' is ambiguous
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xstring(772): could be 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>::operator =(_Elem)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xstring(767): or       'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>::operator =(const _Elem *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xstring(762): or       'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>::operator =(const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xstring(707): or       'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>::operator =(std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &&)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(std::string, A)'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: this compiles fine both on Clang 3.2 and GCC 4.7.2. It is likely a VC10 bug

Comment: Hmm.  `xvalue` vs `lrvalue` (is that right?)-- but not sure how that causes a difference.  Can you include the entire error message you are getting?

Comment: @Yakk: just tried it: "No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous"

Comment: yea looks like a VC bug.  VC sometimes has issues with template inside template.  I think this is an example of that.

Comment: Ok different behaviour on different compilers, bad news. I guess I will just have to accept that it can't work. In practice I avoid this problem with a member function A::as<T> rather than the implicit cast operator.

Comment: I would like to remark that if you change std::string to char (or some non-template type), then it works.  VC has traditionally had issues with template inside template.  MS has fixed a lot of those problems, but it looks like they haven't fixed every.  +1 Good catch!

Comment: for whichever constructor of `std::string` is to be picked, a user-defined conversion is needed. i'm not sure how they are ranked in this case, but i believe in case of copy-initialization only standard conversions are allowed (or at least this is what § 13.3.3.1/4 seems to say). if that's true, there shouldn't be ambiguity and it should convert to `const char*`.

Comment: Also remark that if you cast the result of a.child() to (A&) then it works, but if you cast to (const A&), then it doesn't work.  It's definitely a bug in the compiler, but you can guess what kind of bug...

Comment: Also remark that the IDE flags the error as "Error: more than one user-defined conversion from "A" to "std::string" applies".  One more data point...

Comment: The EDG parser in VS2012 rejects this too but does not in the Comeau implementation.  Definitely looks by design, possibly related to VC extensions.  This feedback article looks similar, also the best place to ask the devs about this: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/735697/conversion-operator-ambiguity

Answer (score 3):

It seems like a VC10 bug to me and it is **not related** to `std::string`.

**BUG ISOLATION:**

I brought it down to the following example:

```
#include <string>

class B
{
public:
    B(char const*) { }
    B(B&&) { }
};

class A
{
public:
    operator char* const () { return 0; }
    operator B () { return B(0); }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    B b1 = a; // fine
    B b2 = A(); // error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'A' to 'B'
                // No constructor could take the source type, or constructor
                // overload resolution was ambiguous.
}
```

Class `B` has a move constructor and a constructor which take a `const char*`. When trying to initialize `b2` from an `rvalue`, VC10 seems to fail to select the conversion operator to `B`.

Both Clang 3.2 and GCC 4.7.2 select the conversion operator to `B`.

**C++ STANDARD RULES:**

Paragraph 8.5/16 of the C++ Standard mandates:

[for this case of copy-initialization,] *"user-defined conversion sequences that can convert from the source type **to the destination type** or (when a conversion function is used) to a derived class thereof are enumerated as described in 13.3.1.4, and the best one is chosen through overload resolution (13.3)"*

If we consider all the available conversion sequences in our example from the source type (`A`) to the destination type (`B`), then the one which involves `A`'s user-defined conversion function to `char const*` requires a *further* conversion (done through `B`'s constructor that accepts a `char const*`) in order to reach the **destination type** `B`. Therefore, it is one step longer than the one that uses `A`'s user-defined conversion function to `B` (per 13.3.3.2), which makes the latter preferable.

This seems to confirm that it is a VC10 bug.

Comment: but if i removed  "operator char* const () { return 0; }", it compiles.  I think this is a different problem, but no doubt related.  The other issue has just 1 template function.  I suspect it has to do with how VC decides to instantiate the template function.

Comment: @thang: right, it's not related with the fact that it cannot convert to `B`, but rather that it fails to select that conversion during the copy-initialization. it believes both constructors are equally good, while the constructor taking `B&&` should be preferred. i am try to figure out why this is true though